# How to parse xml string column with pyspark

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to parse multiple xml files with pyspark. All xml files have the same known schema.
First  I load all the files as text to spark DF:

```
path = 'c:\\path\\to\\xml\\files\\*.xml'
df = spark.read.text(path)
```

At this point my DF looks like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| value                                                                                     
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|<Msg><Header><tag1>some str1</tag1><tag2>2</tag2><tag3>2022-02-16 10:39:26.730</tag3></Header><Body><Pair><N>N1</N><V>V1</V></Pair><Pair><N>N2</N><V>V2</V></Pair><Pair><N>N3</N><V>V3</V></Pair></Body></Msg>|
|<Msg><Header><tag1>some str2</tag1><tag2>5</tag2><tag3>2022-02-17 10:39:26.730</tag3></Header><Body><Pair><N>N4</N><V>V4</V></Pair><Pair><N>N5</N><V>V5</V></Pair></Body></Msg>|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

xml file schema is as follwoing:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Header: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tag1: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tag2: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tag3: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- Body: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Pair: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- N: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- V: string (nullable = false)
```

So the final output after parsing should look like this:

```
+---------+-----+------------------------+---+--+
|tag1     | tag2| tag3                   | N |V |
+---------+-----+------------------------+---+--+
|some str1| 2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.730 |N1 |V1|
|some str1| 2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.730 |N2 |V2|
|some str1| 2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.730 |N3 |V3|
|some str2| 5   |2022-02-17 10:39:26.730 |N4 |V4|
|some str2| 5   |2022-02-17 10:39:26.730 |N5 |V5|
+---------+-----+------------------------+---+--+
```

Meaning "Header" element should repeat itself for all NV pairs that come from the same xml string.
So I think I found a way to extract all the header tags with `xpath` or `xml.etree.ElementTree` but my problem is that I don't really understand how to extract my NV pairs to something that I can explode later.

What am I missing?

---- Clarification ----
I tried to load my xml files with

```
path = 'c:\\path\\to\\xml\\files\\*.xml'
df = spark.read.format('xml').option('rowTag','Msg').schema(schema).load(path)
```

But this option does not enable providing `*.xml` path so this is why I read my files as text.

Comment: I think it was related to my local spark version. I've updated it and also added HADOOP_HOME to my path so now ```path = 'c:\\path\\to\\xml\\files\\*.xml'
df = spark.read.format('xml').option('rowTag','Msg').schema(schema).load(path)``` works perfectly!

Comment: P.S. No need for all thar double backslashes in the path. "Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters. As a result, in string literals, '\U' and '\u' escapes in raw strings are not treated specially" https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('xml').options(rowTag='book').load('books.xml')
```

See https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#python-api

Comment: I tried this one, but here I cannot provide path with *.xml, but specify the exact xml file name. In my real world use case I have millions xml files that I need to parse so my input file, as I mentioned will be path = "s3://bucket/*.xml". That's why I am reading all the files as text instead of using format('xml') option.

Comment: @NinaVolfenzon ok, spark-xml can also parse XML in a string-valued column in an existing DataFrame with from_xml see https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#parsing-nested-xml

Comment: I looked through this documentation before I posted my question but didn't come out with any relevant solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your spark version, you have to add this to the environment. I am using spark 2.4.0, and this version worked for me. [databricks xml version](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/tree/v0.7.0)

```py
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.7.0 pyspark-shell'
```

The input_path.xml looks like the following:

```xml
<Msg><Header><tag1>some str1</tag1><tag2>2</tag2><tag3>2022-02-16 10:39:26.730</tag3></Header><Body><Pair><N>N1</N><V>V1</V></Pair><Pair><N>N2</N><V>V2</V></Pair><Pair><N>N3</N><V>V3</V></Pair></Body></Msg>
<Msg><Header><tag1>some str2</tag1><tag2>5</tag2><tag3>2022-02-17 10:39:26.730</tag3></Header><Body><Pair><N>N4</N><V>V4</V></Pair><Pair><N>N5</N><V>V5</V></Pair></Body></Msg>
```

```py
input_path = 'src/input/input.xml'

xmlDF = spark.read.format('xml').option('rowTag', 'Msg').load(input_path)

xmlDF.printSchema()
```

```sh
root
 |-- Body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Pair: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- N: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- V: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tag1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tag2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tag3: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Since you can't explode 2 lists in the same query, you can divide it that way:

```py
xmlDF.select(
        '*',
        explode("Body.Pair.N").alias('N')
    ).select(
        'N',
        explode("Body.Pair.V").alias('V'),
        col("Header.tag1").alias('tag1'),
        col("Header.tag2").alias('tag2'),
        col("Header.tag3").alias('tag3'),
    ) \
        .dropDuplicates() \
        .show(truncate=False)
```

It will give the following result based on your input:

```sh
+---+---+---------+----+----------------------+
|N  |V  |tag1     |tag2|tag3                  |
+---+---+---------+----+----------------------+
|N2 |V1 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N4 |V5 |some str2|5   |2022-02-17 10:39:26.73|
|N1 |V3 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N5 |V5 |some str2|5   |2022-02-17 10:39:26.73|
|N5 |V4 |some str2|5   |2022-02-17 10:39:26.73|
|N4 |V4 |some str2|5   |2022-02-17 10:39:26.73|
|N1 |V1 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N3 |V3 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N2 |V2 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N3 |V2 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N1 |V2 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N3 |V1 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
|N2 |V3 |some str1|2   |2022-02-16 10:39:26.73|
+---+---+---------+----+----------------------+
```

Comment: I tried this one, but here I cannot provide path with *.xml, but specify the exact xml file name. In my real world use case I have millions xml files that I need to parse so my input file, as I mentioned will be path = "s3://bucket/*.xml". That's why I am reading all the files as text instead of using format('xml') option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was related to my local spark version. I've updated it and also added HADOOP_HOME to my PATH. So now:

```
path = 'c:\\path\\to\\xml\\files\\*.xml'
df = spark.read.format('xml').option('rowTag','Msg').schema(schema).load(path)
```

Works perfectly!